# Why the type of a parameter of a function in a class would change into list?

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

```
class Employee:

    num_of_emps = 0
    raise_amount = 1.04
    
    def __init__(self, first, last, pay):                     
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first + last + '@gmail.com'

        Employee.num_of_emps += 1
    
    def fullname(self):
        return f'I am {self.first} {self.last}'

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay * Employee.raise_amount)

    @classmethod                                                  
    def set_raise_amt(cls, amount):
        cls.raise_amount = amount
    
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, emp_str):
        first, last, pay = emp_str.split('-')
        return cls(first, last, pay)

    @staticmethod                                               
    def is_workday(day):
        if day.weekday() == 5 or day.weekday() == 6:
            return False
        return True

class Developer(Employee):
    raise_amount = 1.50

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, prog_lang):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay)
        self.prog_lang = prog_lang

class Manager(Employee):

    def __init__(self, first, last, pay, employees=None):
        super().__init__(first, last, pay)
        if employees is None:
            self.employees = []
        else:
            self.employees = employees

    def add_emp(self,emp):
        if emp not in self.employees:
            self.employees.append(emp)

    def remove_emp(self,emp):
        if emp in self.employees:
             self.employees.remove(emp)

    def print_emps(self):
        for emp in self.employees:
            print('--->', emp.full_name())







dev_1 = Developer('John','Doe',30000, 'Python')
dev_2 = Developer('Emily','Smith',23000, 'Java')

#  print(help(Developer))

print(dev_1.email)
print(dev_2.email)

print(dev_1.pay)
dev_1.apply_raise()
print(dev_1.pay)


mgr_1 = Manager('Sarah','Smith',34000, [dev_1])

print(type(mgr_1.employees))
print(mgr_1.employees)
print(type(dev_1))
print(type([dev_1]))
print([dev_1])

mgr_1.print_emps()
```

I recently studied this code on youtube. So basically this code started with a class named 'Employee' at the beginning, and then a subclass called 'Developer' was created. I still able to catch up with the logic behind the code at the moment, but after another subclass called 'Manager' was created, I lost.

I don't know why the parameter,'employees' in the class 'Manager' would suddenly become a list in the end
And I also don't know why the for loop could be able to run

Please help, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
mgr_1 = Manager('Sarah','Smith',34000, [dev_1])
first='Sarah', last='Smith', pay=34000, employees=[dev_1]
```

Your parameter is an list

Comment: Oh I see 
But how could 'dev_1' become a list ? 'dev_1' is an instance of class 'Developer'

I just follow the youtube video to put the square brackets at the 'employees' parameter because if the square brackets are removed there will be another totally different result when running the code. To be honest,  I'm also quite confused about why there should be square brackets added at the 'employees' parameter.

Comment: [object,int,str,dict],[ ] In python, it is list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).